# Spring @Service defined in Kotlin file results in 'UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean' when referenced

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have an existing Springboot/Java application and I wanted to start migrating the application to Kotlin.  I create a @Service in Kotlin, and my unit test fails at runtime because Spring can't find my service.

My unit test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = arrayOf(Application::class))
class Junit5SpringKotlinTests {
    @Autowired // Springboot ConfigurationProperties (application.yaml) mapped to Java bean.  This works.
    lateinit var applicationConfigurationJavaBean: EnvironmentProperties

    fun appProperties(): EnvironmentProperties.Environment? {
        return applicationConfigurationJavaBean.environments[applicationConfigurationJavaBean.activeEnvironment]
    }

    @Autowired
    lateinit var testServiceKotlinBean :TestService  // My Kotlin @Service which can not be found at runtime.

    @Test
    fun `ApplicationConfiguration`() {
        println(appProperties()?.baseClientId)
        testServiceKotlinBean.hello()
    }
}
```

My Kotlin service:  TestService.kt

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class TestService {
    fun hello() {
        println("hello from service")
    }
}
```

My error at runtime executing the unit test:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'Junit5SpringKotlinTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'testServiceKotlinBean'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'api.model.TestService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'api.model.TestService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
```

FWW, I am able to write JUnit5 SpringBootTests in Kotlin test code and exercise all my Java components, so this has something to do with Kotlin components being discovered at runtime by Spring.  Java components work.

I suspected this might be a build problem and have seen similar issues.  I have the following included in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

so that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the package name I used for the Kotlin service.  Kotlin is nice in that I don't have put my files in the same package path like java.  But my Spring classpath scanning was relying on a package: A.B.C and below and my Kotlin path only had C.  I changed the package name in my Kotlin file to be A.B.C.TestService and all is fine.  Yay.

Comment: I believe I have the same problem. How exactly did you changed the pakage name in the Kotlin file?